# Displaying user data from Firebase Firestore in React Native within a Text tag

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**Background**
Hey! I'm trying to build a header for the home page of my app. I have succesfully implemented email/password auth with Firebase and also persistent credentials. However, I am unable to fetch data from the firestore collection which stores my users.
Basically, what I need is to have my header display "Hello {userName}", but I have absolutely no clue on how to do that.
My Home Screen is a function component, not a class component, so as far as I know I can't go the "componentDidMount()" way.

**Question**

Which is the best way to fetch the current user's data and display a specific field of information, such as their first name?

How would I go about rendering that within a `<Text>` tag? Is it something like `<Text> Hello {this.user.firstName}</Text>` or am I absolutely wrong?

**What I've tried**

I know this has something to do with this line of code: `const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')` but I've no idea what to follow it up with. Also have tried with this method:

```
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var firstName, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

    if (user != null) {
    firstName = user.firstName;
    email = user.email;
    photoUrl = user.photoURL;
    emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    uid = user.uid; 
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work. On the last example I'm calling firstName like this: `<Text>Hello {firstName}</Text>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing auth with firestore. Firebase auth only provides credentials and the ability to login and does not enter any data into a database (firestore). What you want to do is when a user is registering you want to set a corresponding document in firestore with the users uid (identification) and all of the users custom data (First name, etc).

Here is an example:

```
  const onRegister = async () => {
    try {
      const credential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        'email@email.com',
        'password',
      );
      const {uid} = credential;
      // your data here (dont forget to store the uid on the document)
      const user = {
        firstName: 'whatever',
        lastName: 'whatever',
        user_id: uid,
      };
      await firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set(user);
    } catch {
      //do whatever
    }
  };
```

and then when you wanna get their data you can access their document and display it:

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const {uid} = auth().currentUser;

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const documentSnapshot = await firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();

      const userData = documentSnapshot.data();
      setUser(userData);
    } catch {
      //do whatever
    }
  };

  // Get user on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  // return info if user is set
    return (
      <Text>{user && user?.firstName}</Text>
    );
```

Comment: Before anything else, thanks a lot! This was really useful, however, I don't really understand how it's doing what it's doing, and I kinda can't get it to work. Could you explain the first part of the code so I can really understand it?

Comment: The first function registers a user in firebase auth with an email and password  using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function. That function returns a user credential which we then get the user id (uid) from. With that user id we create a corresponding firestore document under our user collection storing all the data for that user (first name, etc). Then whenever you need that user data you use the user id to access it.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late, I've got one last question, what would be the corresponding imports for the HomeScreen in order to get this to work this way? I keep getting a "can't find variable auth" error. Also thanks a lot for the explanation,it helped a lot.

Comment: Well you need to import auth: import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';